# New MongoDB PHP Driver : How to display multple documents using MongoDB\Driver\Query

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using new mongodb driver for PHP and using query want to display all relevant documents. But instead it returns only one document or boolean(false) as value.

I want all the mongo documents to be returned which satisfies the condition. Tried using limit parameter option too but to no avail.

Below is my code :

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
//$filter = [ 'job_id' => [ '$gte' => 1 ], ];
//$options = [ 'maxScan' => 400 ];
$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]); 
$rows = $mongo->executeQuery('sag.jobs', $query, $readPreference); // $mongo contains the connection object to MongoDB
//var_dump($rows);
$abc=current($rows->toArray());

var_dump($rows);
//print_r($abc);
var_dump($abc);
?>
```

Used both with option and filters parameter and as a empty parameter :

Mongo table content:

```
> { "_id" : ObjectId("596608c7f4bb66cead9762d6"), "job_id" : 1 } { "_id"
> : ObjectId("596608caf4bb66cead9762d7"), "job_id" : 2 } { "_id" :
> ObjectId("596608cef4bb66cead9762d8"), "job_id" : 3 } { "_id" :
> ObjectId("596608d0f4bb66cead9762d9"), "job_id" : 4 } { "_id" :
> ObjectId("596608d2f4bb66cead9762da"), "job_id" : 5 }
```

and this is the only output I am getting :

```
object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
  ["_id"]=>
  object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID)#5 (1) {
    ["oid"]=>
    string(24) "596608c7f4bb66cead9762d6"
  }
  ["job_id"]=>
  float(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following lines of code should give you the results as an array:

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$arr = $client->sag->jobs->find($filter)->toArray();
```

For more information on the MongoDB\Collection::find method, [see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/#examples). For more information on the MongoDB\Drive\Cursor object it returns, [see here](http://php.net/class.mongodb-driver-cursor).